# What indexes should I create to speed up my queries on this table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a table with the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transactions]
(
    [ID] [varchar](18) NOT NULL,
    [TIME_STAMP] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [AMT] [decimal](18, 4) NOT NULL,
    [CID] [varchar](90) NOT NULL,
    [DEPARTMENT] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [SOURCE] [varchar](14) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    )
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The table has 75 million rows in it. Somehow, it takes up 20 GB of disk space!

The following 2 queries...

```
SELECT 
    SUM(AMT) 
FROM 
    Transactions
WHERE 
    TIME_STAMP >= '2017-11-11 00:00:00' AND 
    TIME_STAMP < '2017-11-12 00:00:00' AND
    DEPARTMENT = 'Shoes' AND
    SOURCE = 'Website'


SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(CID))
FROM 
    Transactions
WHERE 
    TIME_STAMP >= '2017-11-11 00:00:00' AND 
    TIME_STAMP < '2017-11-12 00:00:00' AND
    DEPARTMENT = 'Accessories' AND
    SOURCE = 'Mobile'
```

...each take about 2 minutes to run!

The DEPARTMENT and SOURCE fields are of low cardinality, they contain only a few distinct values.

Please advise on what I need to do, which indexes I need to create with which settings to optimize performance of these queries.

Thank you!

Comment: If you run those queries in a modern version of management studio with a modern version of SQL Server (basically, any versions you *should* be using these days) and ask for the execution plan, "missing" indexes should be suggested. Note that the automated advice is far from perfect so should be treated as a suggestion rather than "you must implement this index precisely as I've just told you"

Comment: I'm not seeing a clustered index mentioned. It could be that you're incurring the cost of forwarded records in (what appears to be) a heap.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this specific query would be a composite index (one index with multiple columns) in this order:

1. Department
2. Source
3. Timestamp

Try to put the most selective column first, so if source has more possible variations than department, put it first. The date will obviously go last since it will trigger an index scan.

Comment: It might be a good idea to inlcude AMT and CID so it also doesn't have to access data pages, although it will delay update and insert times.

Comment: OP specifically stated that both Department and Source have very limited ranges. In this particular instance, Timestamp would probably be a better choice as the first column.

Comment: I don't think so @SMor, even with a low cardinality, the index scan will be highly reduced by starting the index with department and source. It is always faster to reduce the index with data you can access instantly instead of data you need to scan.

Comment: That's true @EzLo, but it highly depends on the size of his records. It won't make the query slower, but it's difficult to tell how faster it will be either. OP can certainly give it a try if his queries are still too slow.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Transactions ON Transactions(TIME_STAMP,DEPARTMENT,SOURCE) INCLUDE(AMT,CID)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what about your answer solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I would create an index using Timestamp, Department and Source. I would also add AMT and CID as included columns. This means both your queries could be satisfied by reading the index and not having to hit the parent table at all.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_Transactions ON Transactions(TIME_STAMP,DEPARTMENT,SOURCE) INCLUDE(AMT,CID)
```

Answer (score 0):

One additional option to consider is to run the Execution Plan and see if it recommends an index. I do this a lot when considering indexes because I have seen performance improvements from Execution Plan recommended indexes, over indexes that I thought were good, but were not intuitive.